# Round robin not functioning well

Tags: laravel

I try to create a function using round robin where all user in a group will be moderator for every meeting created.For example, a group have 2 users, I managed to create the first two meeting with the two users, but when I created the third meeting, it become null.

```
     public function addsession(Request $req)
           {           
            $mod = null;
            $latestUserId=Meeting::where('groupID', $req->groupID)
            ->latest('id')
            ->first()
            ?->meetingModerator;
        
            //the first meeting or all the users have already had their turn
            $firstUserId=DB::table('group_user')
            ->where('group_id', $req->groupID)
            ->orderBy('user_id')
            ->first()
            ?->user_id;
        
            //second time meeting is being held
            if ($latestUserId) {
            $nextUserId=DB::table('group_user')
                ->where('group_id', $req->groupID)
                ->where('user_id', ">", $latestUserId)
                ->orderBy('user_id')
                ->first()
                ?->user_id;
            $mod = $nextUserId;
            } else {
               $mod = $firstUserId;
                }

        $data = new Meeting;
        $data->groupID = $req->groupID;
        $data->meetingDate = $req->meetingDate;
        $data->meetingTime = $req->meetingTime;
        $data->meetingModerator = $mod;
        $data->save();
    }
```

Model group.php

```
class Group extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    use HasFactory;
    public $timestamps=true;
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
    public function creators()
    {
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
}
```

Model user.php

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    use HasApiTokens;
    use HasFactory;
    use HasProfilePhoto;
    use Notifiable;
    use TwoFactorAuthenticatable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var string[]
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'role'
    ];
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
    public function grp()
    {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Group::class);
    }

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
        'two_factor_recovery_codes',
        'two_factor_secret',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    /**
     * The accessors to append to the model's array form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $appends = [
        'profile_photo_url',
    ];
}
```

Model meeting.php

```
class Meeting extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public function gr()
    {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Group','groupID');
    }
}
```

Comment: "it become null": what does this mean?

Comment: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'meetingModerator' cannot be null

Comment: `$mod = null;` It starts as `null`, and the following conditions still allow it to be `null`: `$mod = $nextUserId;` and/or `$mod = $firstUserId;`, but since both use `?->user_id;`, it can still be `null`. Maybe add some logic to prevent trying to save if `$mod` is `null`, like `if (!$mod) { return 'Unable to Save; $mod is null'; }`, etc.

Comment: So sorry, I am a bit confused about the logic. So, how I want to prevent it become `null`?What should I add to make the system pick the first user for the third meeting?

Comment: You wrote the logic... You're using the `null safe` operator `?->`. This means that if `->first()` returns `null`, `?->user_id` will be `null`. I don't know _why_ `->first()` would return `null`, I can't see the table records, but it is and you're allowing it. You need to handle that case, either by debugging your queries to ensure they don't return `null`, or adding a statement to prevent trying to save if `$mod` is `null`, like I suggested already.

Comment: i see...Actually that null safe code i got it from other people in here also,  so if i dont want to use the `null safe`, is there another way to write the logic that would not return `null`?

Comment: If you don't use the `null safe` operator, your code will produce errors if `->first()` returns `null`, since `null->user_id` is not valid. This is what I mean by you need to debug your queries and determine *why* they are returning `null`. If your code is expected to use `$mod` *only if it is not `null`*, you, and **only you** need to handle that properly.